# How to bind user input with a BigDecimal object field in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

In my project I have a class with `BigDecimal` as one of its fields.

```java
@Entity
public class Product {

    // ...
   
    @DecimalMin("0.01")
    private BigDecimal price;

    // ...
}
```

In *thymeleaf* I have a form with inputs for fields of this class and the one responsible for `price` is:

```html
<form ...>
   <input type="number" step="any" th:field="*{price}">
</form>
```

When the `@ModelAttribute` is returned from this form, the `price` field of `product` is null. It used to work when the `price` was a `double`. How can I make this work? I thought of a workaround - to have this input as a `@RequestParam` and then initialize the `Product.price` using the `double` value 'manually' but is there some solution so that thymeleaf does that for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should work. I just tested this using Spring Boot 2.3.0 as follows:

I am using a form data object, as directly using your entity for a form clutters reposibilities too much IMO:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.DecimalMin;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class ProductFormData {

    @DecimalMin("0.01")
    private BigDecimal price;

    public BigDecimal getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(BigDecimal price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

With a controller like this:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/product")
public class ProductController {

    @GetMapping
    public String product(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("product", new ProductFormData());
        return "product";
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String doSaveProduct(@ModelAttribute("product") ProductFormData formData) {
        System.out.println("formData = " + formData.getPrice());

        return "redirect:/product";
    }
}
```

And the `product.html` template like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http:www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Product</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Product</h1>
<form th:action="@{/product}" th:object="${product}" method="post">
    <input type="number" step="any" th:field="*{price}">
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I type a number in the form and press 'submit', I see the value printed in the console.

Comment: So something like a DTO? Like an object for only retrieving data from a form? (Which is then used for creating entity object?) Wouldn't it be bad for performance?

Comment: Indeed. I then either would have an `toProduct()` method on `ProductFormData`, or pass the `ProductFormData` to a service method (E.g. `service.addProduct(ProductFormData)`, or even convert the `ProductFormData` to `AddProductParameters` (E.g. `service.addProduct(formData.toProductParameters())`). This ensures you can use a rich domain model for your entities. I have not seen any conditions where this was a performance problem.

Comment: By "reach domain model for entities" you mean for example a situation where I'd like to expand my entity class somehow? Thank you for your answers by the way, they really help but I don't fully understand what are the benefits of using `ProductFormData`.

Comment: I mean that `ProductFormData` typically only uses `String`, `int`, `BigDecimal`. Where in your entity, you might use a `Price` class, or a `Quantity` class. Of maybe in your `Product`, you have a `Supplier` reference, but in `ProductFormData`, you use `String supplierId` because that would be easier to bind to the Thymeleaf form.